# Android Datatable

Tags: android, sql, database

I'm working on an application , I currently I have a database the rows are transferred to arrays then displayed in a datatable.

I'm a novice with this, I'd just like to know what is the best way to edit these rows. I can retrieve a row by the id in some edittext boxes then edit and update. But is there a more intuitive way to do this for the user? like an alternative to a datatable where the table itself its editable?

Hopefully I explained that well enough

Advice would be great, thanks

Comment: You could try using the `Cursor` and `CursorAdapter` built into android to parse/display the information.  This should be a little easier than transferring everything into an array.  But in terms of how you actually want to present it to the user may require more information about your particular application.

Comment: Somehow the best is *not* dumping the data to array. Just work directly to the cursor would be the best on performance.

Comment: I found it pretty straightforward to use a ResourceCursorAdapter subclass to map database rows to a list adapter.  If your table can be implemented as a list of rows, that would be one way.

Comment: ok thanks - it seems i need to investigate cursors, its a simple calculator really, a name and an amount for each row but they need to be easily editable, with a total at the bottom. then the same again another section with name and an amount with a total and an overall total amount at the bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it outside your application then keep the emulator running, and update the tables in your application's database using the command prompt. 
adb shell is the command to access the application's database